# how to create c3js Bar chart from json array

Tags: c3.js

if i have a json array like the below json

```
[
 {id: 27, name: "ACT LIFE BU1", count: 360}
  {id: 38, name: "ALUMATREND BU2", count: 802}
  {id: 36, name: "ASPATREND BU2", count: 350}
  {id: 28, name: "AVOSOYA BU1", count: 569}
]
```

how to make a chart like the below picture

[image]

many thanks for your help,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the introductory tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, not a help forum. Please take the tour, visit the help center and especially read how to ask and "Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Agree with @nbwoodward in general. You may find useful instruction and examples at the [c3.js examples page](https://c3js.org/examples.html). Good luck and please do come back when you have a problem to solve.